# Parent is absolute; Give child an scroll bar only when it exceeds the parent height bound

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

After digging into some search results, I have discovered that, I am trying to achieve something completely different.

In my case, The child `div` will initially contain a little text. Eventually more texts will be appended into the child. When the text `height` exceeds the parent `div`'s `height`, then the child `div` should be scrollable. Problem is, the scrollbar appears right after a new text is appended into the child. It ignores the case whether the child `div` height exceeded that of the parent.

```
<div id="parent" style="position:absolute; top : 40px; height:auto; bottom : 60px; overflow-x:hidden;>
    <div id="child" style="overflow-y:auto">
        <p style="text-align:center;">some text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

How to resolve my case ?

Comment: The scrollable item should have a fixed height, so it "knows" when to start scrolling (or be able to calculate it according to the parent div). You could, for example, set a `height: 100px;` to the parent div and then set a `max-height: 100%;` to the child div.

Answer (score 0):

```
.child{
   top:0;
   bottom:0;
  overflow-y:auto;
  position:absolute;
}
<!--update -->
    <div id="parent" style="position:absolute; top : 40px; height:300px; bottom : 60px; overflow-x:hidden;">
        <div id="child" style="overflow-y:auto">
            some text <br />
            some text <br />
            some text <br />
            some text <br />
            some text <br />
            some text <br />
            some text <br />
            some text <br />
            some text <br />
            some text <br />
            some text <br />
            some text <br />
            some text <br />
            some text <br />
            some text <br />
            some text <br />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: please see my edit. Setting the child div as absolute breaks the paragraph text to be centered right.

Comment: change the height of parent to fixed value for example 100px;

Answer (score 0):

it works perfectly try this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tbtefcu7/1/)

```
<div id="parent" style="position:absolute; top : 40px; height:200px; bottom : 60px; overflow-x:hidden;border:1px solid red;">
    <div id="child" style="overflow-y:auto;width:100px;">
        some text
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i did not fix the child height